# Confusion in output of double negation as failure

Tags: prolog, negation-as-failure

I am trying to learn prolog and i came across the following problem:

Given -

```
try(X):-not(not((member(X,[a,b,c])))),write(X).
```

I would expect the query `?- try(X).`, for the following query to be something like

```
X=a
a;
X=b
b;
X=c
c.
```

But in fact, the output is:

```
?- try(X).
_12010
true.
```

Why is that? Why the variable is not initiated to some value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to what @VictoriaRuiz says, notice a few other things:

```
?- \+ member(X, [a,b,c]).
false.
```

This is false because `member(X, [a,b,c])` has solutions, but the variable binding is lost when you negate it. So that means

```
?- \+ \+ member(X, [a,b,c]).
true.
```

is the same as

```
?- \+ false.
true.
```

In other words, there's nowhere for X to materialize from. Your `write(X)` happens outside the scope of the variable binding for X, it's as though you did this:

```
?- \+ false, write(X).
_4082
true.
```

which is basically the same as

```
?- write(X).
_4014
true.
```

If you wanted to see evidence of backtracking in the negation, you might expect to see it with this query:

```
?- \+ \+ (member(X, [a,b,c]), write(X), nl).
a
true.
```

But because you obtained a true solution on the first try, the negation of that is false. Then the negation of that is true. So we see that it produced a solution inside the goal `(member(X, [a,b,c]), write(X), nl)`, which is enough to know that the negation of that is false. Negating false again gives you true, but no variable bindings.

Answer (score 3):

Prolog operates with a [closed world assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-world_assumption). You provide a knowledge base and only what is in it is true.

When you negate, Prolog doesn't know what values to check for. It can't add "a" as a part of this universe that is worth checking. And since it can't check for anything, it just returns nonsense.